# Typo3 widget.paginate creates a broken url for next page

Tags: typo3, fluid, templating

Hi guys so I am trying to create an extension that takes a json file and displays images, so far so good but I would like to paginate through the 500+ images, this is where it goes bad.

I am trying to use the widget.paginate in fluid, the images are displayed but when I click on the 'next' link I get a url that does not work `http://localhost/work/index.php?id=7&tx_llgcinfinitescroll_message%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=2`

I get a typo3 error -  #1518472189 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\PageNotFoundException

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{imageData}" as="paginatedImages"
                       configuration="{itemsPerPage: 24, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 0}">

        <f:for each="{paginatedImages}" as="image" key="i">
            <!-- Assigning Variables -->
            <f:variable name="thumbnail" value="{image.imageData.thumbnail}"/>
            <f:variable name="fullSizeImage" value="{image.imageData.fullSizeImage}"/>
            <f:variable name="imageHeight" value="{image.imageData.imageHeight}"/>
            <f:variable name="label" value="{image.imageData.label}"/>
            <f:variable name="welshLabel" value="{image.imageData.welshLabel}"/>
            <f:variable name="description" value="{image.imageData.description}"/>
            <f:variable name="welshDescription" value="{image.imageData.welshDescription}"/>

            <!-- Displaying Images -->
            <div class="grid__item">
                <div class="hovereffect">
                    <a href="{fullSizeImage}">
                        <img src="{thumbnail}" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="{label}">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
        </f:for>
    </f:widget.paginate>
```

If someone has any idea what I'm doing wrong please let me know, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you simplified the 'next' link in your post? If not, it's missing a cHash. Combined with [FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError] =true (default), this will end in a 404.

Comment: Hi Julien Thanks for your help, after a lot of time spent on google, I am yet to find a solution to this problem. I am unsure on how to add missing cHash? also, I have noticed that if I have google debugger open I get a 404 for the next page of the pagination but if I close the debugger I get page one over and over again no matter what page I am on.

Comment: Normally, a URL contains a cHash or, if the page is not cached, a no_cache parameter. Your 'next' URL does not contain both. That's weird.
Did you deactivate [FE] [pageNotFoundOnCHashError] once in the install tool? This could help during debugging. The question here is less about how to get the cHash into the URL, but rather why it is not there (anymore).